# Angular - Async pipe not updating View when AfterViewInit emits a new value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component which holds a `BehaviorSubject`. In my template I use `async` pipe to update the view and get the latest value from my `BehaviorSubject`.

When the value is emitted from `OnInit` lifecycle hook, the `async` pipe updates the view with the correct value. But when I try to emit a value from `AfterViewInit`, the `async` pipe does not update the view.

Is this correct behavior? Why `async` pipe won't update the second emitted value?

Example component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  
  public test$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // All three values are logged - 0, 100, 200
    this.test$.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // View is updated with 100 value
    this.test$.next(100);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // View is not updated, async pipe is not triggered
    this.test$.next(200);
  }
}
```

Example component template:

```html
<h1>{{ test$ | async }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `OnPush` change detection strategy. You should trigger check for changes manually:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // View is not updated, async pipe is not triggered
    this.test$.next(200);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

`ngOnInit` is called before a view is checked. so `100` will be displayed at first.

`ngAfterViewInit` is called after an initial check for your view has been done. Since you are using `OnPush` change detection strategy, it will not trigger a change automatically.

Comment: Why do I have to do it maually and the view is not updated automatically via `async` pipe? New value is emitted so I suppose the view will be updated via the `async` pipe.

From docs - "When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes."
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` - because of this